# Discord.py: Get user object with id

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

I have a bot which only saves the id of a user (it's better working like that). Now I want to get the user-object from that id.

I tried following which doesn't work for me, maybe I have made something wrong..

```
client = discord.Client
client.get_user(id)
```

and `client.get_user_info(id)`

Here is the code:

```
import discord
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    ntd = name_table.get_all_records() #google sheets api: returns a list of dicts
        async def on_message(self, message):
             print(message.content[1])
             if message.author == client.user:
                return
             if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
                await self.handle_DM(message)
             if message.content[0] == "/":
                if message.content.split(" ")[0].lower() == "/rank":
                   await self.rank_command(message)
       
       async def rank_command(self, message):
        if len(message.content.split(" ")) < 2:
            await message.channel.send(
                message.author.mention + "/rank takes 2 or 3 arguments. Do '/rank ?' for help.")
        try:
            if message.content.split(" ")[1] == "?":
                await self.help("rank", message)
                return
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if message.content.split(" ")[1] == "top":
                await self.top_rank_command(message)
                return
        except:
            pass
     async def top_rank_command(message):
          print("Top rank entered")
          _user = await client.fetch_user(372746847393021953) #my id: Cluebo#2312
        print(_user)
        print("Top rank end")
```

Executing this, it will only print `"Top rank entered"` but not the `user` or `"Top rank end"`
However, I did not get an error message. The method just stops there (The bot is running on Heroku).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods to get a user from an id:

- [`Client.fetch_user(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch#discord.Client.fetch_user) (or [`Bot.fetch_user(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=fetch%20user#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_user)) → returns a [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User) object
- [`Guild.fetch_member(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch#discord.Guild.fetch_member) → returns a [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object

Here are some examples (using both `Client` and `Bot`):

```py
#Get a discord.User object
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content[6:]
    if message.content.startswith('!find'):
        user = await client.fetch_user(int(content))
        print(user)
    else:
        pass

@bot.command()
async def find(ctx, id: int):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(id)
    print(user)
```

```py
#Get a discord.Member object
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content[6:]
    if message.content.startswith('!find'):
        member = await message.guild.fetch_member(int(content))
        print(member)
    else:
        pass

@bot.command()
async def find(ctx, id: int):
    member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(id)
    print(member)
```

With those examples, you'd just have to write `!find [id]` in discord and it would print the object it fetched in your terminal

Comment: I tried your first recommendation with my own id. It should print the result in the terminal, but I have the same problem as before.. I don't know why it stops without an error..

Comment: The whole code is too long, but I will include the necessary stuff

Comment: My bad, forgot to await the methods, I've edtite the post

Comment: i guess the old methed was client.get_user_info... changed to bot.fetch_user? either way.. this worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

client.fetch_user(id(int)) is a coroutine. This means that I need to add an `await`, so it needs to be `_user = await client.fetch_user(id)`. Make sure the id is correct, because it can happen that the script stops then without an error.