# Issue with sending dm messages discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a command in my bot that allows a user to dm an anonymous message to me. However, when I tested the command my bot only sends the first word of the message to me.

```
    @commands.command(name='msgetika', aliases=['msgmax'])
    async def msgetika(self, ctx, message1=None):
        '''Send an annonymous message to discord'''
        if message1 is None:
            await ctx.send('Please specify a message')

        maxid = await self.bot.fetch_user('643945264868098049')
        await maxid.send('Anonymous message: ' + message1)
        msg = await ctx.send('Sending message to max.')

        await ctx.message.delete()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

        await msg.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `*` if you want to catch the entire phrase. [View the docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) about using this and have a look at the example working beneath the code.

```py
   @commands.command(name='msgetika', aliases=['msgmax'])
    async def msgetika(self, ctx, *, message1=None):
```

[image: using * and args]

Also, unless you are using an older version of discord.py, [user ids are `int`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63768847/14420546).

```
maxid = await self.bot.fetch_user(USER ID HERE)
```